# Resource 'GUID value here' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, change-password, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to change an Azure AD user password.

The user is already authenticated in a **SPA** application using the *implicit flow* and the `adal` library.

While calling:

```
return await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(new User
                {
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                    {
                        Password = userPasswordModel.NewPassword,
                        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
                    },
                });
```

I'm getting this exception:

> {"Code: Request_ResourceNotFound\r\nMessage: Resource
>   '35239a3d-67e3-4560-920a-2e9ce027aeab' does not exist or one of its
>   queried reference-property objects are not present.\r\n\r\nInner
>   error\r\n"}

Debugging the access token I got with `Microsoft Client SDK` I see that this **GUID** is referring to the `oid` and `sub` properties. See below:

[image]

This is the code I use to acquire the token:

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp =
     ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Startup.clientId)
            .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, Startup.tenant))
            .WithRedirectUri(Startup.redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(Startup.clientSecret)
            .Build();

            var authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { MSGraphScope }).ExecuteAsync();

            return authResult.AccessToken;
```

I'm using the *implicit flow* in a **SPA** application. While doing `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` I see that my user is authenticated and all claims are present.

I've read a lot of docs @ GitHub and Microsoft Docs but it's still not clear in my mind how to implement this.
By the way, I'm using these Microsoft Graph packages:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="0.1.0-preview.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I guess I'm not approaching this correclty because instead of acquiring a token for the application I should acquire a token for the user. Should I use `clientApp.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` instead?

If so what's the recommended way of acquiring a token for the currently logged in user using Microsoft Graph API SDK?

Can you shed some light?

**#######** EDIT **#######**

I was able to make some progress using this:

```
var bearerToken = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as string;

JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(bearerToken);

var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(jwtToken.RawData, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

IEnumerable<string> requestedScopes = jwtToken.Audiences.Select(a => $"{a}/.default");

var authResult = clientApp.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new[] { MSGraphScope }, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

return authResult.AccessToken;
```

but now I'm getting the error:

> insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
>   authorization_requestdenied

Comment: Just after posting this question, I found this https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of

Comment: I'm a little confused. You mention using the Implicit OAuth grant but the token you're getting contains `Roles` rather than `scp`. Roles are Applications copes (Client Credentials) which implies you're not using Implicit here. What you want is Implicit using the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope.

Comment: Just to clarify, Application scopes (`roles`) cannot be used to reset user passwords. Only Delegated scopes support resetting passwords. This ensures that any password reset can be audited back to a specific user ("a throat to choke" as they say).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks for stopping by and for the clarification. I resorted to using the original `clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient` instead of `clientApp.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf`. Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long debugging session (8 hours or so) I was finally able to get what I wanted after I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747507/114029) by @Michael Mainer.

This is the "right" code I put together:

```
public async Task<User> ChangeUserPassword(UserPasswordModel userPasswordModel)
{
    try
    {
        var graphUser = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount();

        var newUserInfo = new User()
        {
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                Password = userPasswordModel.NewPassword,
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
            },
        };

        // Update the user...
        return await graphClient.Users[graphUser.ObjectId].Request().UpdateAsync(newUserInfo);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

> Note 1: `graphClient.Users[graphUser.ObjectId]` is being used instead of `graphClient.Me`
>
> Note 2: `.ToGraphUserAccount()` is from Microsoft.Graph.Auth.

I had a sample `PATCH` request in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) that correctly set a new password for the user.

[image]

The **Access Token** used in Postman's `Authorization` request-header had the same format\properties from the one I was acquiring with Microsoft Graph API. I just compared them using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). So I must've been calling something wrongly...

I used `clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient` instead:

```
var authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { MSGraphScope }).ExecuteAsync();

return authResult.AccessToken;
```

where:

```
MSGraphScope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```