# Microsoft graph /me/mailFolders not working while permissions are given

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have a office 365 account and Iwant to access my emails

I followed Microsoft graph documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I have selected the permissions asked as you see below :

[Permissions Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3AfI.png)

I have requested the token and the following request does not work :

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders`

```
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

But when I use the next one , it works :

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('xxx.yyy@zzz.onmicrosoft.com')/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages`

I need to use the first endpoint which everybody is using on the internet , I can't get why I doesn't work for me

Comment: This is happening because you have configured the app only flow like client credential flow with Application permissions. The reason here is the App token doesn't have any clue what is '/me' which talks about the logged in user as the app is logged in here but not the user. Configure any flow with User token and delegated permissions to your app in Azure AD and then try that call. You can also use [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) which is a good example for delegated permissions for testing.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity thanks for your response .Graph Explorer shows needed persmissions for every endpoint. What I concluded is that it is caused by the Directory.Read.All (with admin consent) that I don't find among my permissions , do you why?

Comment: me/mailFolders need Mail.Read permission which doesn't need admin consent. Try to give that permission and use the call

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I added it too but /me/messages has the same error while /me is returning Resource '32f1.." does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Answer (score 0):

In Graph, the `/me/` endpoint is an alias for the currently signed in user (based on the token). An application without a user present will not be able to query `/me/`, and should instead specify the user id of the user of interest (`/users/user id`).

If you call this endpint `/me/mailFolders` which means listing the mailFolders of the currently signed in user. So you need to add **[delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)** and use the flow **except** **[client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions)** to get access token.

If you still would like to use application permissions, you need to call this endpoint `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders`.

About the error(*Resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.*), see the code sample of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569459/13308381).

Comment: I had an Oauth token, and I can get the response of /me but can not get the response of /me/mailFolders, it shows ErrorAccessDenied. But I already add the API permission "Microsoft Graph - Mail.Read" in my AAD.

Comment: @YitongFeng Try with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), check the status of Mail.Read in modify permissions(Preview). You need to accept the permission when signing your account in with auth code flow.